# How to Connect Ionic Mobile App to Backend API Using Spring?

Tags: spring, api, ionic-framework, backend

Does anyone know how to connect the ionic mobile app to backend api using spring and sqlserver as its database? If you have some references or examples, then it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few tutorial that might be useful to you.
(These are not using sql server, doesn't matter much)
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/05/17/develop-a-mobile-app-with-ionic-and-spring-boot
https://blog.ionicframework.com/creating-an-ionic-app-with-mysql-and-backand/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have first the documentation of your backend or to know the methods of the backend with URL. you can find many videos and tutorial on google. it depends about what you need (Authentification, getting data, streaming.... ).